# Java: polymorphism applied to Map generic types

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

I want to have a function which (for example) outputs all the values of a Map in both cases:

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
output(map1, "1234");
output(map2, "4321");
```

And the following doesn't seem to work:

```
public void output(Map<String, Object> map, String key) {
    System.out.println(map.get(key).toString()); 
}
```

Are not both `String` and `Integer` of type `Object`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Map<String, String>` does not extends `Map<String, Object>`, just like `List<String>` does not extend `List<Object>`. You can set the value type to the `?` wildcard:

```
public void output(Map<String, ?> map, String key) {  // map where the value is of any type
    // we can call toString because value is definitely an Object
    System.out.println(map.get(key).toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are looking for is the attempt in Java to introduce polymorphism on `Collections` and is called [**Generics**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). More specific to your use case, [**Wildcards**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html) will fit the bill.

An **Unbounded Wildcard** (see details in Wildcards link) is used by @manouti in his answer, but you can use something more specific than just that: an **Upper Bounded Wildcard**.

E.g. `Map<String, ? extends Object>` where `Object` usually is the most specific but still common class from which all used classes must be derived. For example, if the values in all of your Maps will have a common parent (or 'super') class `YourParentClass`, then you can replace `Object` in my example by that class name.